# Why use Angular Service to gather information, instead of just $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

Two options, which is better and why:

Example A.

1. app module
2. service containing model data
3. controller to call in data from service

File 1: `Users.js`:

```
      angular.module('users', []);
```

File 2: `userService.js`:

```
angular.module('users').service('userService', ['$q', UserService]);

  function UserService($q) {
    var users = [
      {
        name: 'Bob Smith',
        age: 26,
        address: 'London',
      },
      {
        name: 'John Simpson',
        age: 41,
        address: 'New York',
      },
      {
        name: 'Maria West',
        age: 36,
        address: 'Chicago',
      }
    ];

    // Promise-based API
    return {
      loadAllUsers : function() {
        // Simulate async nature of real remote calls
        return $q.when(users);
      }
    };
  }

})();
```

File 3: `UserController.js`:

```
          angular.module('users').controller('UserController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.selected     = null;
        $scope.users        = [];
        $scope.selectUser   = selectUser;
        $scope.toggleList   = toggleUsersList;
        $scope.makeContact  = makeContact;

        userService
          .loadAllUsers()
          .then( function( users ) {
            $scope.users    = [].concat(users);
            $scope.selected = users[0];
          });
}]);
```

Example B:

1. app module, and controller drawing model data from from .json file through $http service.
2. json file to hold model data.

File 1: `Users.js`:

```
      angular.module('users', []);

         .controller('userController', [
            '$scope', 
            '$http', 
            function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

            $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.userData = data; 
            });

         }]);
```

File 2: `userService.json`

```
         [
          {
            'name': 'Bob Smith',
            'age': 26,
            'address': 'London',
          },
          {
            'name': 'John Simpson',
            'age': 41,
            'address': 'New York',
          },
          {
            'name': 'Maria West',
            'age': 36,
            'address': 'Chicago',
          }
        ];
```

B seems more logical (and easier to me), but I've seen people do A. I presume there's an advantage - can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, A looks preferred approach, because it looks kind of following `separation of concern`, and following Single Responsibility Principle.

**Service**

- Which is responsible for getting data from back-end
- Exposed various method to other component to retrieve data from single place.

**Controller**

- Communicate between services and the views
- Also it handles other view specific business logic.

---

### Why Approach B is bad?

You have simple ajax call inside a controller itself. Ya that's look really nice.

But suppose you wanted to have `userData` to be displayed on two other page, then what will you do? I know you are going to replicate same code inside other controller too. And here the problem comes in to picture. Same thing is going to get repeat for multiple times for no reason. Correct? So replicating code on multiple places will add `Code Maintainability` problem in future. That's the reason, you shouldn't go for first approach.

Where as go for approach `A` would have better maintainable & structured code.

**Edit**

Inside your `approach A` you shouldn't be hard code all the data. It should retrieve from server either by calling server API method or call to `.json` file. Also I'm going to write down correct service code `approach A`, you could see after this explanation end. By looking at refactored code, you can see now we had get rid of `$q` service. Because you don't need to worry about custom promise implementation, as `$http` methods does return `promise`, by using which code can follow promise chain pattern by take use of `.then`

```
angular.module('users').service('userService', ['$http', UserService]);
  function UserService($http) {
    return {
      loadAllUsers : function() {
        // Simulate async nature of real remote calls
        return $http.get('users.json'); //return promise from herer
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, very clear explanation! I'm a little bit confused about the steps in A, but will work at it - this is a good start. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Paulos3000 do you still have any doubts about approach A?

Comment: Yes actually I do! 

I'm a little uncertain why the model data is installed in the service function... does this not make retrieval and update of the model date more precarious/difficult? I would have thought it would be better to have the data isolated in a .json file, not touching the angular code. Also I can't get my head around the $q parameter of the service function, and the necessity for/function of the 'Promise API'.

Comment: Just thinking about it... could you use the $http request within the service to pull in data from an external .json file? Is there any disadvantage to doing this?

Comment: @Paulos3000 hey you mean to say you are going to put all the data into service.js? is it what you are asking? basically that should be `ajax call` to server(it could be json). I think you were confused because you have had hard coded data in `approach A`.. correct? Apology for late reply :(

Comment: @Paulos3000 look at my edit in answer, let me know if you still have any doubts about it. Cheers

Comment: I'm going off someone else's example which already had the data hardcoded - I originally assumed that was necessary but have since figured out it was probably just a shortcut. Makes sense now :) Thanks for the help. If you can explain the use of the Promise API - $q.when() - that would also be really helpful.

Comment: Just saw the edit. Great explanation. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Paulos3000 `$q.when` was there because you are considering dummy data should return in kind of `asyn` manner, and it returns out data with `promise`, by which you are able to apply `.then` function over it. That's it.  Glad to know that my explanation is good(still I felt I'm grammatically too bad).. Thanks & Happy coding :)